# Convergence of $ x_n = \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{n} \right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to show that the sequence $ x_n = \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{n} \right)^n$ is convergent.

Using calculus in $ \mathbb{R}$, we could see that $ \lim _{n \to \infty}  \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{n} \right)^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} e^{n \ln \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{n} \right)} = 0   $. I do not need to calculate the limit of the sequence, just to check it convergence. The definition of convergence doesn't look like a good idea, so I've been trying to use a trick like we do in calculus or to show that the sequence is bounded and monotonic. My guess is the last idea is better than the first one. If I show that $ x_{n+1} < x_n $, since $x_n $ is clearly bigger than zero we are done. But how to show it? i've tried induction withou success. Is there a better way to show it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* $\dfrac12+\dfrac3n \le \dfrac78$, when $n\ge8$.

Answer (score 5):

If $n>18$, then 
$$\frac12+\frac3n<\frac23$$
so
$$\left(\frac12+\frac3n\right)^n<\left(\frac23\right)^n$$
because $\left(\frac23\right)^n\to0\,\,$ as $\,\,n\to\infty$, we get that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac12+\frac3n\right)^n=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the root test for the convergence of the series $\sum x_n$:
$$
\sqrt[n]{x_n} = \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{n} \right) \to  \frac{1}{2} < 1
$$
This implies that the series $\sum x_n$ converges and hence that $x_n\to 0$.

Comment: Why should I show that this series converges since I am talking about a sequence?

Comment: @user2768645, I did because $x_n$ has that $n$-power, which vanishes in the root test. Of course, this trick only works if $x_n\to 0$. But it does prove two things at the same time: that $x_n$ converges and that the limit is $0$.